# mssql query for auto complate

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, autocomplete

When I question a word, it completes the word or adds new words to it.
Unique first 10 recordings.

```
declare @Category table (CategoryName  varchar(50)) 

insert into @Category (CategoryName) values('phones')
insert into @Category (CategoryName) values('phone blue')
insert into @Category (CategoryName) values('phone pink')
insert into @Category (CategoryName) values('phone big')
insert into @Category (CategoryName) values('phone big bang')
insert into @Category (CategoryName) values('bad phone blue')
insert into @Category (CategoryName) values('bad phone pink')
insert into @Category (CategoryName) values('bad phone but good')
```

I would like the following result when calling as category name "phone"

- phone blue
- phone pink
- phone big
- phone but

I would like the following result when calling as category name "phon"

- phone
- phones

Comment: This is really not an appropriate problem for a relational database.

Comment: Looks like a case for `WHERE Category like 'phone%'`to me

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @Category table (CategoryName  varchar(50)) 

insert into @Category (CategoryName) values('phone blue')
insert into @Category (CategoryName) values('phone pink')
insert into @Category (CategoryName) values('phone big')
insert into @Category (CategoryName) values('phone big bang')
insert into @Category (CategoryName) values('bad phone blue')
insert into @Category (CategoryName) values('bad phone pink')
insert into @Category (CategoryName) values('bad phone but good')
insert into @Category (CategoryName) values('phone')
insert into @Category (CategoryName) values('silly phone')
insert into @Category (CategoryName) values('lost phone ')
insert into @Category (CategoryName) values('white phone user')
insert into @Category (CategoryName) values('some device')
insert into @Category (CategoryName) values('phoner homer')
insert into @Category (CategoryName) values('space phone  ')
insert into @Category (CategoryName) values('jam phone  hex doc')

declare @Formword varchar(50) = 'phone';

select    CategoryName
        --, charindex(@FormWord,Categoryname)
        --, charindex(@FormWord,Categoryname) + len(@FormWord)-1
        --, charindex(' ',CategoryName,charindex(@FormWord,Categoryname) + len(@FormWord))
        --, ltrim(right(categoryname,(len(categoryname)-charindex(' ',CategoryName,charindex(@FormWord,Categoryname) + len(@FormWord)))))
        --, charindex(' ',ltrim(right(categoryname,(len(categoryname)-charindex(' ',CategoryName,charindex(@FormWord,Categoryname) + len(@FormWord))))))
        --, left(ltrim(right(categoryname,(len(categoryname)-charindex(' ',CategoryName,charindex(@FormWord,Categoryname) + len(@FormWord))))),charindex(' ',ltrim(right(categoryname,(len(categoryname)-charindex(' ',CategoryName,charindex(@FormWord,Categoryname) + len(@FormWord)))))))
        , case  when charindex(' ',ltrim(right(categoryname,(len(categoryname)-charindex(' ',CategoryName,charindex(@FormWord,Categoryname) + len(@FormWord)))))) = 0
                    then @Formword + ' ' + ltrim(right(categoryname,(len(categoryname)-charindex(' ',CategoryName,charindex(@FormWord,Categoryname) + len(@FormWord)))))
                else 
                    @Formword + ' ' + left(ltrim(right(categoryname,(len(categoryname)-charindex(' ',CategoryName,charindex(@FormWord,Categoryname) + len(@FormWord))))),charindex(' ',ltrim(right(categoryname,(len(categoryname)-charindex(' ',CategoryName,charindex(@FormWord,Categoryname) + len(@FormWord)))))))
          end [next word]

from @Category
where 1 = 1
        and CategoryName like '%' + @Formword + '%'
        and len(CategoryName) > len(@Formword) + 1
        and charindex(@FormWord,Categoryname) + len(@FormWord) < len(Categoryname)
```

Comment: Hey there! While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I am grateful to you.
But there is a problem in the question. When I question "phon", only "phone" should come to the end.
Could you make the results unique and limited to the first 10 records?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @Category table (CategoryName  varchar(50)) 

insert into @Category (CategoryName) values('phones')
insert into @Category (CategoryName) values('phone blue')
insert into @Category (CategoryName) values('phone pink')
insert into @Category (CategoryName) values('phone big')
insert into @Category (CategoryName) values('phone big bang')
insert into @Category (CategoryName) values('bad phone blue')
insert into @Category (CategoryName) values('bad phone pink')
insert into @Category (CategoryName) values('bad phone but good')


declare @searchWord varchar(50) = 'phone';
declare @res int;

set @res = (select case when (select count(*) from @Category
                 where substring(CategoryName, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', CategoryName)) = @searchWord) > 0
                 then 1
                 else 0
            end)
if(@res = 1)
begin
    select top 10 CategoryName from @Category where CategoryName like''+@searchWord+'%' and CategoryName like '% %' order by CategoryName
end
else
begin
    select top 10 CategoryName from @Category where CategoryName like''+@searchWord+'%' and CategoryName not like '% %' order by CategoryName
end
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: When the word "phone" is interrogated, the following result: phones,phone blue, phone pink, phone big, phone but